# How Do i request a user to have input inot a batch file and then add it into a command?

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, cmd

OK, so I've never written a batch file before, but I have now got to the point where I need a batch file but as far as I'm aware it's going to be quite complex. So, basically this is what I need to do:

I need a batch file that will ask the user a few questions and then use their answers to complete a command to be run in the `cmd.exe` in Windows.

The command for my machine is as follows:

```
csvde -f C:\output -d "cn=Users,dc=test,dc=local" -r "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))" -l "givenName, sn, objectGUID"
```

So I need a batch file that would ask the customer the info to go in the fields of the `"dc=test"` and the `"dc=local"` and then execute the finished command.

Any sort of help would be excellent, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:testlp
(set test=)
set /p test="Please enter test value "
if not defined test goto testlp
```

then use `dc=%test%` rather than `dc=test`

Leave you to figure out how to input `local` all by yourself...